# Pine Script error: Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

I have next code:

```
var int i = 1
if specificCandle
    while (na(f) and bar_index - i >= 0)
        if close[i] < linePriceLow
           f := high[i]
        i := i + 1
```

In this part of code I got next error:

> Error at 48:0 Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

I would like to understand cause of problem and solve it